# XLowerWindow Acts Like XRaiseWindow

Tags: x11, xorg

I have a program that needs to raise and lower its window in X11. Send XRaiseWindow works fine, but when I call XLowerWindow, the window behaves as if XRaiseWindow was sent. It brings itself to front of the screen.

The X11 windows is created in a fairly standard way. The event mask is set to FocusChangeMask | ExposureMask | PointerMotionMask | KeyPressMask.

CWOverrideRedirect is false.

_NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN is set to 1.

Any ideas on this behavior. Do need to unset the fullscreen flag before I lower?

Comment: do you see the same behavior when try without WM?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are missing a XSync/XFlush to get the window to repaint after lowering it?